# How to apply Cochran-Armitage trend test in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working on a publication examining rising authorship of minorities for certain articles. There is a clear increasing trend, but I wanted to apply some statistical rigor. My data frame is simple: Years, and % minority authorship. However, Cochran-Armitage input dataframe doesn't make sense in my context. Am I using the right test?

I have perfected the dataframe and prepared it by producing the number of years on the x-axis, and the % minority authorship on the y-axis. essentially 1 row, and 10 columns (each column representing one year). However, cochran-armitage cannot accept 1 row dataframes

my dataframe exists as so

`year 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 
race 11.1 12.1 14.2 15.2 19.2 20.5 21.8 27.9 30.1 31.1`

Comment: According to wikipedia, Cochrane Armitage is for association between a variable with 2 categories and an ordinal variable with K categories. I would say wrong test. What about simple linear regression? (take the % as the Y axis value...)

Comment: I can create an additional category that is essentially the compliment of what I have there. Interprested as non-minority (i.e. a 1 - value). This is a similar paper that used it https://www.thespinejournalonline.com/article/S1529-9430(17)30315-7/fulltext. Can I use a linear regression to imply an increasing trend? Is a simple linear regression appropriate in this situation?

Comment: I would say yes, the trend is pretty strong. You don't have a lot of points, but it seems to be significant. I'll put this into an answer...

Comment: With regards the paper you linked - the Cochrane Armitage is more appropriate there as they have 2 categories (female/male) and an ordinal with k variables (first, middle, last). That's why they can apply the test in their situation, in yours you have 2 categories, but no ordinal variables.

Comment: Why would first middle and last be the ordinal? If we want to argue a trend in successive fashion, wouldnt we use year?

Comment: see section on ordinal variables [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-interval-variables/).  Year could be considered ordinal too, though I would consider it continuous variable rather than ordinal normally.

Comment: You are analyzing percentages as the outcome, so it’s by definition not going to be normally distributed. Beta regression is more likely to meet the distribution of percentages because beta distributions have bounds of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cochrane Armitage is likely to be the wrong test, it is for association between a variable with 2 categories and an ordinal variable with K categories. You have two variables each with one category.

I think a simple linear regression would work. In fact, when you run one on the data you provided (you are missing the % for 2018, so I removed that row), this is what you get:

```
> summary(y_p)

Call:
lm(formula = year ~ percent, data = y_p)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.77079 -0.38560 -0.03582  0.35535  0.90139 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.004e+03  5.428e-01 3692.52  < 2e-16 ***
percent     4.045e-01  2.526e-02   16.01 2.32e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5586 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9697,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.966 
F-statistic: 256.4 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 2.319e-07
```

This looks fairly significant to me, but you would need to check the residuals etc to be sure.

Comment: Just because you don’t get an error does not provide assurance that your statistical analysis is correct.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I'm not statistician by any means. Your comment regarding B-regression looks like the best solution to OP's problem